# get_flat_tensor_specs nest.flatten(element_spec), []) results in AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_flat_tensor_specs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

### AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_flatten_tensor_specs'

1. problem:
   Currently, when creating an iterative process with a build federated averaging process, I am able to pass in a functools. partial successful.
   however, there must be an error in the above code that produces a structure needed for the model_fn to go through
   correctly.
2. have tried:
   looking at the input data. This custom data set is built for a autoencoder and the original TF solution never used labels. As this solution is built to take in the training data, train the model, then work on the test data, and validate on the validation set to produce a threshold.
   There might be a issue with the underlying production.
3. sources:

```py
        df, y_train = get_train_data(sysarg)
        x_train, x_opt, x_test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1,
                                           random_state=17),
                                          [int(1 / 3 * len(df)), int(2 / 3 * len(df))])
        x_train, x_opt, x_test = create_scalar(x_opt, x_test, x_train)
        input_spec = tf.nest.map_structure(tf.TensorSpec.from_tensor,
                                           [tf.convert_to_tensor(x_train),
                                            tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train)])
        assign_weights_fn = compression_process_adapter.CompressionServerState.assign_weights_to_keras_model
        iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
            model_fn=functools.partial(model_builder,
                                       input_dim=sysarg,                                     input_spec=input_spec),
            client_optimizer_fn=client_optimizer_fn,
            server_optimizer_fn=server_optimizer_fn,
        )
        iterative_process = compression_process_adapter.CompressionProcessAdapter(iterative_process)
```

4. trackback error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-47998fd56829>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py', args=['--experiment_name=temp', '--client_batch_size=20', '--client_optimizer=sgd', '--client_learning_rate=0.2', '--server_optimizer=sgd', '--server_learning_rate=1.0', '--total_rounds=200', '--rounds_per_eval=1', '--rounds_per_checkpoint=50', '--rounds_per_profile=0', '--root_output_dir=B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/logs/fed_out/'], wdir='B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection')
  File "B:\tools and software\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "B:\tools and software\PyCharm 2020.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 306, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 299, in main
    train_main()
  File "B:/projects/openProjects/githubprojects/BotnetTrafficAnalysisFederaedLearning/anomaly-detection/train_v04.py", line 262, in train_main
    server_optimizer_fn=server_optimizer_fn,
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\federated_averaging.py", line 211, in build_federated_averaging_process
    stateful_delta_aggregate_fn, stateful_model_broadcast_fn)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\framework\optimizer_utils.py", line 521, in build_model_delta_optimizer_process
    model_broadcast_state_type=model_broadcast_state_type)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\framework\optimizer_utils.py", line 368, in _build_one_round_computation
    @tff.tf_computation(dataset_type, model_weights_type)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\wrappers\computation_wrapper.py", line 337, in <lambda>
    return lambda fn: _wrap(fn, arg_type, self._wrapper_fn)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\wrappers\computation_wrapper.py", line 89, in _wrap
    concrete_fn = wrapper_fn(fn, parameter_type, unpack=None)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\wrappers\computation_wrapper_instances.py", line 51, in _tf_wrapper_fn
    target_fn, parameter_type, ctx_stack)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\tensorflow_serialization.py", line 274, in serialize_py_fn_as_tf_computation
    result = target(*args)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\utils\function_utils.py", line 517, in <lambda>
    return lambda arg: _unpack_and_call(fn, arg_types, kwarg_types, arg)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\core\impl\utils\function_utils.py", line 510, in _unpack_and_call
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\framework\optimizer_utils.py", line 381, in _compute_local_training_and_client_delta
    client_output = client_delta_fn(dataset, initial_model_weights)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 580, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 627, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 506, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2446, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 2667, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 441, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3299, in bound_method_wrapper
    return wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 968, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
```

5. Additional Error list:

```
    AttributeError: in user code:
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_federated\python\learning\federated_averaging.py:90 __call__  *
        num_examples_sum = dataset.reduce(
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:1932 reduce  **
        add_to_graph=False)
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:3210 __init__
        self._input_structure),
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:270 get_flat_tensor_specs
        nest.flatten(element_spec), [])
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:269 <lambda>
        return functools.reduce(lambda state, value: state + value._flat_tensor_specs,
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_flat_tensor_specs'
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/GIGA-Money/FederatedLearningAnalysis)

Comment: Could you potentially link a stacktrace, where the error is raised from? There don't seem to be any calls to `_flatten_tensor_specs` in the TFF codebase, so I am guessing there is an argument passed to TF that is of the wrong type somewhere.

Comment: and expanded view of the error:
```
AttributeError: in user code:
    ...
   :\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:270 get_flat_tensor_specs
        nest.flatten(element_spec), [])
    B:\tools and software\Anaconda\envs\bookProjects\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\util\structure.py:269 <lambda>
        return functools.reduce(lambda state, value: state + value._flat_tensor_specs,
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_flat_tensor_specs'
```

Comment: Is there an additional exception thrown during the exception in 4 (e.g. is that a partial stack trace)? I suspect there maybe something like "error raised while handling error" and a second stack trace that includes the TFF code. Something that also stands out: it looks like the input_spec might be the _entire_ dataset (depending on what `create_scalar` does...), when TFF is expecting it to be the type signature of a single batch. Maybe try something like `input_spec = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x_train, y_train]).batch(N).element_spec` (this may not work exactly as-is).

Comment: ok, updated the full error listing

Comment: When trying @ZacharyGarrett suggestion: ```
input_spec = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([x_train, y_train]).batch(FLAGS.client_batch_size).element_spec
```
I now get: ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.

Comment: One hypothesis is the use of a list `[]` in defining the spec. Is it possible to replace `[x_train, y_train]` with `(x_train, y_train)`, so that the container is a `tuple`? I've noticed that Tensorflow sometimes tries to do some tensor packing under the hood (list of N tensors -> single tensor with first dimension N) which can fail if the tensors aren't all the same shape.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I have noticed that replacing `[]` with `()` like Zachary suggests produces different type of error (shape mismatch).

Comment: Well, it's been so long at this point, I know I got it working. Here is the public repo, note the usage of old PySyft. [link](https://github.com/GIGA-Money/FederatedLearningAnalysis)